# Failed to deploy MEAN stack on Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, mean

I am getting error when deploying a MEAN app on Heroku, find the log below:

```
Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Error: Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:18:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todoapp-angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todoapp-angular@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the **Procfile**

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

And here is the **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "todoapp-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postnstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~8.5.0",
    "npm": "~5.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.1",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.9",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

The 'www' file which I specified in Procfile contains configuration of Port and other details of Node.JS Configuration.

Note: I am trying one ways to deploy my Angular application. If there's a better way I can improve the architecture of my application, please share with me the idea (a link would be great).
I want have both server and client on the same server.

Comment: Can I see your project structure?

Comment: https://github.com/narengs7/sampleNode.git   <-- GitHub Link

Comment: If you use Angular, then omit the view engine in your app.js. Also, your build folder is dist, not public so fix hour express.static as well.

Comment: Also, start script should just be node app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy to Heroku it will only install the packages that you have listed in the dependencies section of package.json. That means none of the packages in devDependencies will be installed. The same is true for other hosting services. devDependencies are only used in development, but Heroku is considered to be production (NODE_ENV=production).

What you have to do is make sure the dependencies that are needed in production are placed in dependencies. In your case, it complains about *typescript*, but there are probably more. You can easily check what's needed by deleting your node_modules folder in your development environment and then run `npm install --production`. Start the server like Heroku would and look for error messages during startup. Move the packages that the error messages are complaining about into dependencies, one by one until it starts working. I would suggest moving them with `npm uninstall --save xxx` and then `npm install --save xxx` to make sure it's done correctly in both package.json and package-lock.json.

Considering that you build the Angular files on Heroku on deployment (which is normal), you probably need all the packages in dependencies.

`ng serve` is used to start the development server. It should not be used in production. Heroku tries to start it from what I can see from your error message. You probably want to host the front-end with a Node http or Express server.

Finally, you have a typo here:

```
"postnstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
```

It should be "postinstall".

Comment: It worked but i get a new error now "sh: 1: ng: not found"